# How does the removal of attribute nodes affect attributes NamedNodeMap in DOM4?

Tags: javascript, dom, attributes, nodes, language-lawyer

DOM4 removed attribute nodes. [`Attr`](https://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#attr) no longer inherits from [`Node`](https://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#node) and therefore completely changed. [`Element`](https://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#element) methods which retrieved or set attribute nodes were removed.

And `attributes` was moved from [`Node`](https://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#node) to [`Element`](https://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#element). Now its defined as follows:

> ```
> interface Element : Node {
>   [SameObject] readonly attribute NamedNodeMap attributes;
>   ...
> };
> ```
>
> The [*attributes*](https://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#dom-element-attributes) attribute must return a [`NamedNodeMap`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-1780488922).

But `NamedNodeMap` is not defined by DOM4! Instead, it links to DOM Level 3 Core, which says its methods should return nodes:

> ```
> interface NamedNodeMap {
>   Node   getNamedItem(in DOMString name);
>   Node   setNamedItem(in Node arg) raises(DOMException);
>   Node   removeNamedItem(in DOMString name) raises(DOMException);
>   Node   item(in unsigned long index);
>   readonly attribute unsigned long   length;
>   // Introduced in DOM Level 2:
>   Node   getNamedItemNS(in DOMString namespaceURI, in DOMString localName)
>                         raises(DOMException);
>   // Introduced in DOM Level 2:
>   Node   setNamedItemNS(in Node arg) raises(DOMException);
>   // Introduced in DOM Level 2:
>   Node   removeNamedItemNS(in DOMString namespaceURI, in DOMString localName)
>                            raises(DOMException);
> };
> ```

Moreover, in DOM3, `NamedNodeMap` is a general data structure which could be used for other things than attributes. If [`attributes`](https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-84CF096) worked was because it was defined as such:

> - *attributes* of type [`NamedNodeMap`](https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-1780488922), readonly
>
>   A [NamedNodeMap](https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-1780488922) containing the attributes of this node (if it is an [Element](https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-745549614)) or `null` otherwise.

Basically, now the `NamedNodeMap` returned by `attributes` is no longer defined to contain the attributes, its methods are only defined in an obsolete spec, and are supposed to return nodes, but attributes are no longer nodes.

So, Wow. At this point I have no clue about how `attributes` is supposed to work.

Is it still supposed to work? If so, how? If not, why wasn't it removed?

Comment: [It seems I'm not the only one to notice this](https://github.com/w3c/dom/issues/4)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the W3C spec [is wrong](https://github.com/w3c/dom/issues/6#issuecomment-215972553):

> You should not read this spec because it's old snapshot of
>   https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/ and contains a mass of gaps.

The [WHATWG spec](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/) defines it properly.

> [Elements](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-element) also have an ordered [**attribute list**](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-element-attribute) exposed through
>   a [`NamedNodeMap`](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#namednodemap). Unless explicitly given when an [element](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-element) is
>   created, its [attribute list](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-element-attribute) is empty. An [element](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-element) [**has**](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-element-attribute-has) an
>   [attribute](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-attribute) A if A is in its [attribute list](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-element-attribute).

[`NamedNodeMap`](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#interface-namednodemap) is properly defined in that spec, its methods now return `Attr` objects:

> ```
> [Exposed=Window, LegacyUnenumerableNamedProperties]
> interface NamedNodeMap {
>   readonly attribute unsigned long length;
>   getter Attr? item(unsigned long index);
>   getter Attr? getNamedItem(DOMString qualifiedName);
>   Attr? getNamedItemNS(DOMString? namespace, DOMString localName);
>   [CEReactions] Attr? setNamedItem(Attr attr);
>   [CEReactions] Attr? setNamedItemNS(Attr attr);
>   [CEReactions] Attr removeNamedItem(DOMString qualifiedName);
>   [CEReactions] Attr removeNamedItemNS(DOMString? namespace,
>                                        DOMString localName);
> };
> ```

Then, it makes sense when [`attributes`](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-element-attributes) is defined as

> The [**attributes**](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-element-attributes) attribute must return the associated
>   [`NamedNodeMap`](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#namednodemap).

So yes, `attributes` is still supposed to work.